# How to install socket.io in Django Project?

Tags: django, socket.io

I am building games with Django.
But I have one problem
https://pypi.org/project/django-socketio/
I follow this guide.
But It's not working.
[As you can see, there are many issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoBPp.png)

if you have experience to building socket.io sample, please share me, If so, I am really really thanks.

Comment: i am using django channels for websockets(chat, realtime games etc). here is a chat example: https://github.com/suhailvs/channels-chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install django-socketio
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```